# eval command as string for using with Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, eval

Is there a way in Matlab to store command as string for later use?

 For example, if I have

```
x = 1:10;
plot(x, x);
```

can I somehow store the 2nd row as `str = 'plot(1:10, 1:10)'` automatically, so later on I can use the command again simply with `eval(str)`? Any useful functions for helping me with this task?

p.s. I know it's possible to store the line  with `str='plot(x,x)'`, but that's not good enough since it depends on instant values of workspace variable x, which can be changed over time.

Comment: What's your goal? Yes you can simply execute strings using   [eval](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html).

Comment: `eval` is almost never the right answer.  So I agree with @zellus: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @oli, @zellus: my goal here is to perform setstatus commands that were rejected by the server, so I store these commands for later execution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using a closure. In your case that would look like this:

```
x=1:10;
f = @()plot(x, x);
```

Now `f` has everything that is needed to execute the plot (including the information in x) and you can apply it to execute the plot function:

```
f()
```

Comment: It should be noted that MATLAB uses the specific term ["anonymous function"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html) as opposed to "closure" to refer to these types of functions.

Comment: Nitpick: this is not a closure, it is an anonymous function. They behave differently in Matlab. Inline anonymous functions like this get copies of the values in the enclosing workspace's variables it references at the time the handle is constructed. Handles to nested functions are actually closures: they keep "live" references to the variables in the enclosing workspace, and will see later updates to them.

Comment: Ha ha! Looks like @gnovice reads his morning StackOverflow about the same time I do.

Comment: @Andrew: Yay, Eastern Standard Time!